# Converting Macros to VBA from Outside Current Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'd like a way to programatically convert Access macros to VBA modules.  I know how to do this manually.  I was working with some code to do this within the current database and I got it to work.  However, I would like to be able to do this outside of the current database.  I plan to have this program housed with other utility type programs in the same database.   Below is my code.  I am getting a message that says, "Microsoft Access cannot find the test1 you referenced in the Object Name arguement.  Do you have any suggestions on how to acheive what I want to acheive?

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
MsgBox "start here"
Dim strDB As String
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim m As Object

strDB = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\testme.accdb"

Set appAccess = New Access.Application
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDB

For Each m In appAccess.CurrentProject.AllMacros

    Debug.Print m.Name
    DoCmd.SelectObject acMacro, m.Name, True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertMacrosToVisualBasic

Next

Set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoCmd` is a member of the `Application` object. Ask those commands to work from the new `Application` object instance you created (*appAccess*) instead of the `Application` instance which is running your *Command2_Click()* procedure.

```
appAccess.DoCmd.SelectObject acMacro, m.Name, True
appAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertMacrosToVisualBasic
```

In other words, basically do the same for `DoCmd` as you did with `appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase` and `appAccess.CurrentProject` ... you associated them to the specific `Application` instance.